# Using set_value() without name attribute

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I ran into an issue where an `input` field is missing its `name` attribute. I have been unable to set the value of this field with the `set_values()` function, which specifically requires a `name` to assign a value. Here is the function code:

```
function (form, ...) 
{
    new_values <- list(...)
    no_match <- setdiff(names(new_values), names(form$fields))
    if (length(no_match) > 0) {
        stop("Unknown field names: ", paste(no_match, collapse = ", "), 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    for (field in names(new_values)) {
        type <- form$fields[[field]]$type %||% "non-input"
        if (type == "hidden") {
            warning("Setting value of hidden field '", field, 
                "'.", call. = FALSE)
        }
        else if (type == "submit") {
            stop("Can't change value of submit input '", field, 
                "'.", call. = FALSE)
        }
        form$fields[[field]]$value <- new_values[[field]]
    }
    form
}
```

I would like to override `set_values()` with a function that accepts either an input name, an id or other css selector.

Any ideas?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What code have you tried exactly?

Comment: I added some sample code. Hopefully this helps...

Comment: @Adam  Your extra code does help,  but please add yet a little more. You just say "So far, no go", but what isn't going?  Do you get an error message? Does it run but not produce the result you expected? Please describe how this is failing.

Comment: Okay, please see above.

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example. We really need to see the HTML form or to see the `dput()` of `form.unfilled`. Does the field actually have an ID? Your "bandaid"  is' pretty much the way to do things if you just want to update the second element whatever it is. And it should be posted as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Question:  Is it possible to set the value of this field with the `set_values()` function, without referencing the name attribute?

Answer: No. Look at the source code. Any element with no name cannot change the object returned by the `set_values()` function.

If the elements in the `...` argument do not have names (or the element you're looking for doesn't have a name, `set_values()` can't do anything. To illustrate using the extreme case, with no names, it will return its `form` argument unchanged.  See the `for` loop in the source code, `for (field in names(new_values))`  `new_values` is a list of the `...` arguments. If that list is empty, or if `names(...)` is empty, the loop exits immediately and the function returns `form` unchanged.

```
function (form, ...) 
{
    new_values <- list(...)
    no_match <- setdiff(names(new_values), names(form$fields))
    if (length(no_match) > 0) {
        stop("Unknown field names: ", paste(no_match, collapse = ", "), 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    for (field in names(new_values)) {
        type <- form$fields[[field]]$type %||% "non-input"
        if (type == "hidden") {
            warning("Setting value of hidden field '", field, 
                "'.", call. = FALSE)
        }
        else if (type == "submit") {
            stop("Can't change value of submit input '", field, 
                "'.", call. = FALSE)
        }
        form$fields[[field]]$value <- new_values[[field]]
    }
    form
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say "no, it's not possible with the `set_values` function"? Otherwise i'm not sure I see an answer to the question here.

Comment: @MrFlick. I clarified with an edit. It's not possible with that function.

Comment: OK. But it's certainly possible to write a function that would. But I agree that the current version of `set_values` will not.

Comment: Sure, if you have the data. I just thought I'd answer the answerable question :)

Comment: What about modifying the xml input node to add the name attribute before running set_values()? Any ideas along those lines? Thx

Comment: @Adam If you post a reproducible example, we can suggest alternative solutions to your problem. Right now since there's nothing to test with and it's not clear what the input data is, it's a lot of work to write up a solution for any possible set of inputs. If you give a clear example, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @MrFlick How would you override `set_values()` to accept either a name or an id?